# Dynamic chart in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I want to know if there is an option to create a dynamic chart that will give me the same output for a selection of different customers?
My intention is that I have 4 databases, each of a different customer, they all have the same table in the same structure from which I pull the query.
In the end, I want to display a chart in the dashboard, select a customer and it will automatically connect to the customer's database and display the output.
The query must be general and the from must be dynamic according to the customer selection in the dashboard.

Thanks for your answers

I'm trying to find documentation on this subject, but I didn't find.